# Example of BV function that is not $p$-quasicontinuous

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, functional-analysis, measure-theory, soft-question

It is true that a $W^{1,p}(\Omega)$ function is $p$-quasicontinuous, but it shouldn't be true for $BV(\Omega)$ functions.

- What is an example of BV function that is not $p$-quasicontinuous?

Comment: How do you define $p$-quasicontinuity?

Comment: @UmbertoP. There is an open set $U\subset\Omega$ with $\operatorname{Cap}_p(U)<\epsilon$ such that $f|_{\Omega\setminus U}$ is continuous.

Comment: If $p > n$ (for $\Omega \subset \mathbb R^n$), you can take a discontinuous BV function.

Comment: Can you identify sets of small $p$-capacity? What types of sets have $p$-capacity equal to zero?

Comment: @UmbertoP. If the capacity is zero, so is the $s$ dimensional Hausdorff dimension with $s>N-p$. I don't know if the convers holds too.

Answer (score 0):

The relationship between capacity and Hausdorff dimension when $p < n$ is that $\newcommand{\Cap}{\mathrm{Cap}}\Cap_p(E) = 0$ if and only if $\dim_H(E) \le n-p$.

For a simple example, let $n=2$ and $1 < p < 2$. Any circle in the plane will have positive $p$-capacity.

Let $D$ be a disk and define $f(x) = 1$ if $x \in D$ and $f(x) = 0$ otherwise. Let $\Omega$ be an open set containing $\overline D$. Any open set $U$ with the property that $f_{\Omega \setminus U}$ is continuous must contain $\partial D$ and thus cannot have arbitrarily small $p$-capacity.

It is routine to show that this $f$ has bounded variation.